# const char array[] = {set} storing in big endian, I need little endian

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing C for a Big Endian 32-bits microcontroller and I need to store char arrays in ROM:

```
const uint8 font_6x8[570] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // <space>
0x00, 0x00, 0x5f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // '!'
0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00, // '"'
... }

const uint8 font_6x6var[665] = {
0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // <space>
0x02, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // '!'
0x04, 0x03, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // '"'
... }
```

and so on for multiple bitmap fonts to use on a graphic LCD.
My problem is the compiler stores those bytes in Big Endian 4-bytes sets which messes up every character with each other as they're not made of N*4 bytes each.

They're supposed to be `const` and set in ROM so I can't really go and reverse them in the code.

Is there a way to tell the compiler these bytes need to be inserted in Little Endian order. I thought using 8-bits types would enforce this but it doesn't.

Comment: it would maybe help if you say what kinda of MCU and IDE you use, also a link to the lcd datasheet might help, the compiler should NEVER convert int8 to int32 (that just seems very weird) and using int8 should work imo. but i am understanding this right: your compiler and mcu use big endian, but your lcd requires little endian?

Comment: As it is a one off event why not write a script to do the conversion and generate the necessary C code?

Comment: I'm using a pic32mx in mplabx with xc32. Converting the fonts' data seems the only option but I hoped something simpler was possible.

Comment: Since you're storing one-byte units — that's what `const uint8 font_6x8[]` means — there is no endianness; the data is stored in the order you requested it to be stored, one byte at a time.  If you want the data stored in a different order, write the initializers in a different order.  It looks to me like a self-inflicted problem.  If you're planning to read the data as something other than an array of `uint8`, why don't you store it in data of the correct type, with the correct initializer.  Then you don't need to think about the issue.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I have imagined that he got the data from somewhere. I agree that it is self implicted

Comment: Its interesting that 570 and 665 are not multiples of 4. Hmmm.

Comment: This makes little sense, endianess applies to multi-byte integers, not uint8_t. Either you mean the bits in each byte should be reversed, or you just need to swap around 4 and 4 bytes in your array, or something else is going on.

Comment: Ok, I got the data from a program I created in java which lets me draw the fonts and export the data, I could change things around. But there certainly is an endianness problem here. This is the memory content I get from compiling the second font in the example: 
`00000002
02000000
00000017
03040000
00000300
1F0A0600`
You can clearly see it doesn't start with 0x02. I thought it would like JonathanLeffler said but it doesn't.
By the way, 570 and 665 are multiples of 95 characters in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first I had BE and LE definitions mixed up but it's ok
The thing was the IDE shows values in LE when I expected BE, so in the end, my values are not mixed up, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gcc`, try calling it with the flag `-mbig-endian` or `-mlittle-endian` respectively.

Comment: I'm using xc32 from Microchip, I looked up the compiler doc and didn't see the option but tried anyway. It's not recognized.

Comment: From the docs: "This [little-endian] is the default (and only) endianism used by all MPLAB XC compilers."